# How to obtain HttpSession from within the loadUserByUsername method?

Tags: spring-security

My web app is built with Spring MVC (4.2.9.RELEASE) and Spring Security (3.2.5.RELEASE). I use the `loadUserByUsername` method to find the user from the database.

```java
    public class MyUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

            //how to get the HttpSession from within this methd?

        }
        ....
    }
```

How can I get the HttpSession from within this method?

In the `applicationContext.xml` file, I have the following for security:

```xml
<http create-session="always" use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" >

   ....

</http>
```

Comment: In fact loadUserByUserName() method is called only if there is no session and there is no Authentication object associated with SecurityContext, will you explain the use case.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to get current request:
Get the request object from RequestHolderContext and from that one get session:

```
public Optional<HttpServletRequest> getCurrentHttpRequest() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
            .filter(requestAttributes -> ServletRequestAttributes.class.isAssignableFrom(requestAttributes.getClass()))
            .map(requestAttributes -> ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes))
            .map(ServletRequestAttributes::getRequest);
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
Optional<HttpServletRequest> request = getCurrentHttpRequest();
HttpServletRequest currentRequest = request.get();
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Tried your approach and got an exception as follows: ERROR UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:218 - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: No value present
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly you are doing ? You have to copy the function in DerekUserDetailsServiceImpl  class and then call it in the loadByUserName method.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Sorry not being clear in my comment. May be my xml configuration not right?

Comment: I actually have my own implementation, could you please let me know whether you see any issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer exactly to your question at [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-faq-access-session-from-user-service) of more recent version (5.1.5 for instance). In short:

> **How do I access the HttpSession from a UserDetailsService?**
>
> You can’t, since the UserDetailsService has no awareness of the servlet API.

The @Atul's answer can be a good workaround but please be aware that `RequestContextHolder` internally relies on the current thread and thus may miss the session if called from another thread.

Comment: thanks for explanation. I used this functionality but outside the filter, so it works as expected but thanks for your info, it clear some of my understanding. @Curious1, if you want to work with session then you can use spring-session as well. It has lots of functionality and work well with spring-security. It persist the session in DB or Redis, so you can track of session.

Comment: @Toparvion, thanks for the info! Atul, spring-session is not available in the version I use, right?

Comment: I guess, it is. Let me check

Comment: @Toparvion, I actually have my own implementation, could you please let me know whether you see any issue?

Comment: https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springboot_session  This is example of spring-session jdbc implementation. It is spring boot exmaple but the version of spring boot is related to spring4 which you are using right now.

Answer (score 0):

Before making my post, I already have a solution and it seems working, but not sure whether my solution is error-free or Spring already has a more elegant solution. Here is my solution:

I built filter as follows:

```java
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
   ...
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain 
   chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       //create a thread-safe object and record the request object 
   }
}
```

Then, in the `loadUserByUsername` method, get the request object (thus the HTTP session) from the thread-safe object.

Comments? Please feel free let me know whether this approach has any problem.

**UPDATE**

MyFilter is declared in web.xml, together with Spring Security's DelegatingFilterProxy.

Comment: 1. Generally speaking, it is safer to register your filters the same way that Spring does. Thus Spring will take them into account, in particular, will honor their order and call life cycle methods (if needed).

Comment: 2. That thread-safe object must be carefully transmitted from this filter to the `UserDetailsService`. Particularly, if you use static fields, make sure they are set and cleared properly and at the time. But of course its better to use Spring beans for this (see comment above), because then you get the same mechanics as the framework use. This also would ease further unit test coverage.